# Working with large dictionaries in python? (performance and crashing)

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, crash

Goal: to create a python class that will take in a string example 'maple' and translate it into its corresponding species code 'AC'.

Problem: I have created a dictionary that contains all the string inputs and their corresponding species code that will be used for the translation. However I cannot figure out a way to implement the dictionary without python crashing. The dictionary is pretty large (roughly 4000 entries in the format : `{'common name example1': 'species code example1', 'common name example2':'species code example2', ... }` as shown below. I think my code works in theory, but it is taking up such a large amount of memory that python keeps crashing.

Here is my code:

```
import string

class exportSpec:

    def __init__(self, exportSpecobj):
        self.set(self.sani(exportSpecobj))
    def get(self):
        return self.exportSpecobj
    def set(self, exportSpecobj_pre_sani):
        self.exportSpecobj = exportSpecobj_pre_sani

    def puncremove(self, common):
        for c in string.punctuation:
        common = common.replace(c,"")
    return common

    def lower(self, common):
        common = self.lower()
        return common

    def codeChange(self, saniCode):
        codeDict = {'balsam fir':'ABBA', 'white fir':'ABCO', 'maple':'AC', 'freeman maple':'ACFR', 'amur maple':'ACGI', 'rocky mountain maple':'ACGL', 'boxelder':'ACNE', 'norway maple':'ACPL', 'red maple':'ACRU', 'silver maple':'ACSA1', 'sugar maple':'ACSA2', 'tatar maple':'ACTA', 'ohio buckeye':'AEGL', 'horsechestnut':'AEHI', 'serviceberry':'AM', 'broadleaf deciduous large':'BDL OTHER', 'broadleaf deciduous medium':'BDM OTHER', 'broadleaf deciduous small':'BDS OTHER'}

# the dictionary^^ is much bigger but I just showed the first 20ish values to show my code

    check = codeDict.has_key(saniCode)
        if check == "True":
            print("New code was found")
            return codeDict[saniCode]
        else:
            print("Error finding code in Dictionary")
            print(saniCode)
            output = 0
            return output

    def sani(self, exportSpecObj):
        if exportSpecObj is None:
            output = 0
            return output
        else:
            exportSpecObjlcpr = self.lower(self.puncremove(exportSpecObj))
            saniCode = codeChange(exportSpecObjlcpr)
            return saniCode
```

So I think my code works theoretically. The input comes in and gets sanitized with the methods lower and puncremove to remove punctuation and translate to lower case so that the input can be found in the dictionary to be returned as the value found in the dictionary from the key input.

If there is an easier way to do this without using a dictionary that would work too, but this seemed to be the only way I could think of to accomplish this. The common names and corresponding species codes were originally kept in an excel file and I created the dictionary from that.

I just don't have a lot of experience with coding outside of the classroom and have little to know knowledge about memory and performance of programs. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Right now its giving me a SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. How do I find the stacktrace by the way. Apologies for being inexperienced. Python works very slowly when I try to declare the class.

Comment: You can't mix spaces and tabs.  It is recommended by many to use only spaces -- 4 per indentation level.  Also, your `puncremove()` method has its return statement outdented.

Comment: >>> check = codeDict.has_key(saniCode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'codeDict' is not defined
>>>         if check == "True":
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if check == "True":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: I am using IDLE (python 3.5 32 bit) if that helps. IDLE is the "IT" that is being really slow and *seems to be crashing* when I try to declare the class.

Comment: I haven't used Idle for some years, but I seem to recall it got slow with long lines/large output.  You might be better off saving your code to a file, then running it from the command prompt/terminal.  Saving your code in a file should make it easier to sort out your indentation too.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to put large chunks of data in your code. Store the big dictionary in a file and read it in a run time. In Python there's a number of ways of doing this depending on the format of the data and the file it's kept in. In your case the `pickle` module might be a good choice. If you want the data file to be human-readable, using the `json` module would be another.

Comment: Syntax errors have nothing to do with the size of the dictionary. The code you posted had syntax errors so it won't run even if the dictionary is small.

Comment: @martineau Thank you so much. The pickle module worked PERFECTLY.  I got it running as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas.

Example:

```
import pandas

dictionary = {}
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index')
```

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/